# symfony + nginx + Plesk 12 - url rewriting not working fine

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have a symfony project with a lot of requests and users, so I decided to use nginx + php-fpm to get a bit more performance.

But my client wants to have plesk for server administration. So, I installed everything whats required (nginx, fpm, apache) and created the host instance in plesk. Now, the start page of the website works fine - but some child pages gives me a 404 error code directly from nginx, other child pages works.

All urls are rewritten (symfony default). I only renamed the symfony default index file of the web folder `app.php` to `index.php`.

My additional configuration in plesk is: `nothing`

**edit**: I use nginx 1.9.4 (delivered with ubuntu or plesk) and symfony 2.8

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a following lines in "Apache & Nginx settings" > "Additional nginx directives" to your domain in Plesk:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
}
```